# Include template in template Mustache.php

Tags: php, mustache

I have 3 template files:

```
main.tpl
main_header.tpl
main_footer.tpl
```

I need to include the last 2 templates inside the first one using Mustache.php
I can't find documentation about it.

How can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The included templates are called "partials" in Mustache. The tag to include them looks like this:

```
{{> main_header }}
{{> main_footer }}
```

You will need to [set up a template loader](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Template-Loading#partials-loading) so that Mustache can automatically load them.

Since your file extension is `.tpl`, you should also [let your template loader know](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/blob/master/src/Mustache/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php#L38-L41).

The resulting code probably looks something like this:

```
<?php

$m = new Mustache_Engine(array(
    'loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader(
        __DIR__.'/path/to/views',
        array('extension' => '.tpl')
    ),
));

echo $m->render('main', $data);
```